# How to put background of QWidget under other widgets in a QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, background-image, qwidget, qlabel

I've been hours trying to understand(googling) why my widgets are not shown in a QWidget children I am using as a Windows.

The children are mostly QLabel and some QSliders. The Layout is a QGridlayout

here it is some of my window code:

```
FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale()
    {
        this->setWindowTitle("Premier Test");
        this->resize(400, 200);
        QPalette palette;
        palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(QImage("images/metal400x200.png")));

        this->setPalette(palette);
        /*
        this->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(images/metal400x200.png); "
                            "background-position: top left; "
                            "background-repeat: repeat-xy;"
                            );
        */

        buildChildren();
        buildLayout();

        this->setLayout(layout_principale);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

How my children is built

```
void FenPrincipale::buildChildren()
{
    m_title = new QLabel("MonTest");
    m_nextPageButton = new QLabel(">");

    m_line = new QLabel("Slide here");
    m_labelSlider = new QSlider;
    m_result = new QLabel("Result");

    /* 
     * Other children is set here...
    */
}
```

Voilà the result:

[image]

I tried changing fonts and other methods to set the background but the background is always shown over the other widgets.

Am I missing something?

Comment: how are you building your children? what are you doing in the layout methods? The important part of your code is not shown.

Comment: I've just edited the question with a portion of the build process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were close with the style sheet implementation.  I get the correct result with the following:

```
setStyleSheet("QMainWindow { background-image: url(:/images/metal400x200.png) } ");
```

Comment: It doenst work for me, what is QMainWindow doing there by the way?

Comment: @MarcSJ Refer to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html and search for "background-image" on the page.  The reference to QMainWindow causes the background of main window images to be affected by the style sheet.  If your "FenPrincipale" widget derives from some other class, replace QMainWindow with the class it derives from.